# A tidyverse solution to populating a matrix/data frame

Tags: r, join, tidyverse, dplyr

I have a data frame (hit) that contains a single column. This is populated with unique search results.

A second data frame (data) contains the results of the various search queries. The column names identify the search term used and the rows are populated with the search results.

I want to build a matrix or another data frame that is populated according to whether the search result is present or not by column.

I can do this using base R with the following code:

```
    library(tidyverse)
    hit <- read_csv("hit
                     A1 
                     A3
                     B2
                     B4
                     D3")

    data <- read_csv("Search1, Search2, Search3, Search4
             A1, B4, A3, A1
             B4, D3, NA, B2
             D3, NA, NA, B4")



    search <- c("Search1", "Search2", "Search3", "Search4")

    the_matrix <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = 5, ncol = 4)
    rownames(the_matrix) <- hit$hit 
    colnames(the_matrix) <- search

    for (i in search)
        for (j in 1:3){
            result <- data[[i]][[j]]
            row_index <- which(rownames(the_matrix) == result)
            the_matrix[row_index, i] <- 1
        }

    the_matrix[is.na(the_matrix)] <- 0
```

In my mind, there should be a way of achieving this same result with the tidyverse, using the first data frame as the starting point. From there, the second data frame is introduced column by column using the search results as the key to populate.

Can anyone help?

Comment: read_csv is a tidy verse function.

Comment: The code runs on my machine. I just forgot to include the library(tidyverse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data %>% gather(na.rm=T) %>% mutate(p=1L) %>% spread("key", "p", fill=0L)

# A tibble: 5 x 5
  value Search1 Search2 Search3 Search4
  <chr>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
1 A1          1       0       0       1
2 A3          0       0       1       0
3 B2          0       0       0       1
4 B4          1       1       0       1
5 D3          1       1       0       0
```

Comment: Perfect. That was just what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map_df` in combination with `match` and then replace all non-`0`s in `a_tibble` with `1L`.

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
a_tibble <- map_df(data, ~match(hit[["hit"]], ., nomatch = 0L))
a_tibble[a_tibble != 0] <- 1L
a_tibble %>%
  add_column(., hit = hit$hit, .before = 1)
#  A tibble: 5 x 4
#  hit   Search1 Search2 Search3 Search4
#  <chr>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
#1 A1          1       0       0       1
#2 A3          0       0       1       0
#3 B2          0       0       0       1
#4 B4          1       1       0       1
#5 D3          1       1       0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

For your information you can also have a rather elegant base r solution

```
the_matrix=sapply(data,function(x) as.numeric(hit$hit%in%x))
rownames(the_matrix)<-hit$hit
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I find the readability of the tidyverse code a real plus for someone like myself who is started out with little formal instruction. When I look back on some of my older scripts compared to what I write now, its like chalk and cheese.